# logback-splunk failed to instantiate type com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender

Tags: spring-boot, splunk

I have a splunk log setup running Java 17 ubuntu. It uses spring framework and I added logback splunk appender to the project. Building a docker image is good, but the spring boot 3.1.6 application fails to start. If I remove <appender...>, the application starts, and logs print on the console, so the splunk appender is a problem. logback-classic and logback-core dependencies are included in POM.xml.

**logback-splunk.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    ​
    <!-- You can override this to have a custom pattern -->
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
              value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) {%X{request.correlationid} %X{request.formtype} %X{request.endpoint}} %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
    <appender name="http" class="com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender">
        <url>${SPLUNK_URL}</url>
        <token>${SPLUNK_TOKEN_VIPS}</token>
        <source>rsbc-digital-forms-vips</source>
        <sourcetype>rsbc-digital-forms-vips</sourcetype>
        <middleware>HttpEventCollectorUnitTestMiddleware</middleware>
        <disableCertificateValidation>true</disableCertificateValidation>
        <batch_size_count>1</batch_size_count>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%msg</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="http"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**Logging**

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:logback-splunk.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Could not create an Appender of type [com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@6e4784bc - Failed to traverse model appender ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelHandlerException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Could not create an Appender of type [com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@6e4784bc - Failed to traverse model appender ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelHandlerException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:275)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at ca..open.pssg.rsbc.digitalforms.DigitalFormsApplication.main(DigitalFormsApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
    Suppressed: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:44)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:33)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:67)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:241)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:208)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator.processModel(SpringBootJoranConfigurator.java:122)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:170)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:285)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.lambda$loadConfiguration$1(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:247)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.withLoggingSuppressed(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:460)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:242)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
        ... 47 more
    Suppressed: ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelHandlerException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.handle(AppenderModelHandler.java:75)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:241)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:208)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator.processModel(SpringBootJoranConfigurator.java:122)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:170)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:285)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.lambda$loadConfiguration$1(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:247)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.withLoggingSuppressed(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:460)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:242)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding splunk library,

```
<!-- Splunk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```